# Error using deferred.defer on App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use deferred.defer on App Engine (flexible) as per the example on: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred

It's a Python3 app. As the tutorial says, I added these lines to app.yaml:

```
- url: /_ah/queue/deferred
  script: google.appengine.ext.deferred.deferred.application
  login: admin

builtins:
- deferred: on
```

When I deploy the app, I get the error:

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'
```

I'm confused as I don't understand why an App Engine app wouldn't be able to find the google modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `deferred` library was built on top of the push task queues a long time ago, when neither the flexible environment or it's managed VMs predecessor existed yet - the guide you followed is really only applicable to the standard environment.

The push task queues have a limited support in the flexible environment. From the [Task Queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#task_queue) section of [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating):

> The Task Queue service has limited availability outside of the
>   standard environment. If you want to use the service outside of the
>   standard environment, you can sign up for the [Cloud Tasks alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1g6yRocQ3wtdTArfO4JX8DoqOhYmsoTVgrlFnS0mV1bo/viewform?edit_requested=true).
>
> Outside of the standard environment, you can't add tasks to [push
>   queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/#push_queues), but a service running in the flexible environment can be
>   the target of a push task. You can specify this using the
>   [`target`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-tasks#specifying_the_worker_service) parameter when adding a task to queue or by specifying
>   the default `target` for the queue in [`queue.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref)
>
> In many cases where you might use pull queues, such as queuing up
>   tasks or messages that will be pulled and processed by separate
>   workers, [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) can be a good alternative as it offers
>   similar functionality and delivery guarantees.

I have no clue if/how you can use the `deferred` library itself with the alpha task queue support outside of the standard env - I only used the standard env. I'm only speculating that you'd have a better chance of using directly the task queue library (more flexible than the `deferred` library anyways, fewer restriction).

If you choose either of these ways, you'd be in rather uncharted territory, YMMV. Good luck!

One other option could be checking if the pub/sub alternative would be a good fit for what you're trying to achieve using the `deferred` library. Can't comment on it, tho, I didn't use it yet.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I’m disappointed that running Python 3 on App Engine means accepting so many limitations.

Comment: I updated the answer with another potential alternative, maybe it helps a bit more.

Comment: Thx again. I’ll check it out and CRON might work too. I’ll investigate.